# AJAX Read JSON File Line By Line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I've been playing around with AJAX, and I'm trying to read the PHP response line by line and parse that as JSON. Is there a way to parse the entire thing as a JSON array?

Server-side in PHP:

```
<?php
        echo json_encode(array(
                "nick" => "mod",
                "id" => "admin",
                "msg" => "hi"
        ));
    echo json_encode(array(
                "nick" => "other",
                "id" => "1",
                "msg" => "hello"
        ));
?>
```

In JavaScript:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getInfo.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
                $('.div').html('');
                //data.forEach(function (entry) {
                        var name = data.nick;
                        var id = data.id;
                        var msg = data.msg;
                        var html = $('.chat').html();
                        html += "<h5>" + name + " (" + id + ")</h5>";
                        $('.div').html(html);
                //});
        }
});
```

Comment: Why are you reading line-by-line?  There is some streaming JSON code out there but it's finicky... you need the rest of the object for full context.  Just read the whole thing and use `json_decode()`.

Comment: I'm using the same object format for a bunch of different variables. It doesn't have to be line by line, but I'm assuming it would make it easier to parse, plus it would be more human-readable. Also, I'm decoding on the JavaScript end. PHP is outputting the JSON.

Comment: Line-by-line is absolutely not easier to parse... and what does your read method have to do with human readability?

Comment: I want the human readability for debugging purposes, but it's not that big of a deal. Here's what I want the output to look like:
```
`{name:"item one", id:"0"}`
`{name:"item two", id:"1"}`

I want the JavaScript to be able to make an array of objects out of these.

Comment: I'm not asking why you want human readability, I'm asking why reading line-by-line or as a whole object has anything to do with that.  Just use `json_decode()` on the whole thing.  Whitespace in the object structure doesn't matter.

Comment: `json_decode()` is a PHP method. I'm looking to do the decoding in the AJAX code. The optimal case would be a way to use `dataType: 'json'` in the request. I want the success function to receive the JSON array as the data parameter and then `data.forEach()` it.

Comment: Show your code how you are making your AJAX request.  All you need is `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Here is the JavaScript side: http://pastebin.com/Pqtna1Yt. The PHP side is working as intended. The commented out forEach() is just there to show where I want the forEach to go.

Comment: You haven't shown what your data is...  in any case, you're using jQuery, which will parse your JSON for you.  `console.log(data)` and see what you have.

Comment: It prints `undefined` when I just give it multiple lines of JSON (using `json_encode()` twice). Otherwise, it prints out the object.

Comment: Why are you using `json_encode()` twice?  Show your data...

Comment: Right now I'm printing out made up data. http://pastebin.com/r7pmmDii

Comment: Finally... For future questions on Stack Overflow, include all that is needed to reproduce the problem in the first place.  Now that you have finally shown us your code, the solution is obvious.  You're not sending JSON... you're sending a line-delimited file with JSON on each line.  Either have an outer array that includes your objects, or change the data type from JSON in your jQuery request, split lines, and then use `JSON.parse()` on each.

Comment: Okay, thank you. If you post that as a question, I'll set it to the answer. I'd like to close the thread.

Comment: The resulting string from your php is invalid json. Use jsonlint.com to verify the validity. You can't just echo the output from `json_encode(...)` and expect anything sensible to come out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your PHP code.
As you said on comments, your output is `{name:"item one", id:"0"} {name:"item two", id:"1"}`, but ou should get this `[{name:"item one", id:"0"},{name:"item two", id:"1"}]`.

i think that this code below is better:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(array(
        array(
            "nick" => "mod",
            "id" => "admin",
            "msg" => "hi")
        ),array(
            "nick" => "other",
            "id" => "1",
            "msg" => "hello"
        )
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option of `json_encode` like so:

```
json_encode(array(...), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```